# Resume Download not working in android

Tags: android, resume-download

This code for resuming download is not working properly in Android, although it works fine in a Java application. Here I am trying to download a zip file, and it will resume the download, but the net result is an invalid zip file.

```
 BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bout=null;

        try {
            downloaded=0;
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if(ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue()==ECMConstant.ECM_DOWNLOADING){
                File file=new File(DESTINATION_PATH);
                if(file.exists()){
                    downloaded = (int) file.length();
                }
            }
            connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
            connection.connect();
            size=connection.getContentLength();
            Dialog.setMax(size);
             in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
             fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH): new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH,true);
             bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int x = 0;
            while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                bout.write(data, 0, x);
                 downloaded += x;
                 System.out.println(downloaded);
                 onProgressUpdate((int)(downloaded*100/size));
            }

            succes=true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                bout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some details in your question : what is exactly the problem you're facing ? Is there any errors ? If so, can you post thetacktrace ? We need more details if we want to answer you.

Comment: Actually here i am trying to download a zip file...and it will resume download also..but net result is invalid zip file..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int buf = 1024;

if (ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue() == ECMConstant.ECM_DOWNLOADING) {
    File file = new File(DESTINATION_PATH);
    if (file.exists()) {
         downloaded = (int) file.length();
         connection.setRequestProperty("Range",
             "bytes=" + file.length() + "-");
    }
} else {
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
}

connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

progressBar.setMax(connection.getContentLength());
in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
fos = new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH, downloaded == 0 ? false : true);
bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, buf);
byte[] data = new byte[buf];

while ((int x = in.read(data, 0, buf)) >= 0) {
    bout.write(data, 0, x);
    downloaded += x;
    progressBar.setProgress(downloaded);
}
```

Comment: I would also add a `connection.setReadTimeout()` and a `connection.setConnectionTimeout()`

Comment: Hello Lijo, 'ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue() ' i am not understand about this value please give me the reference for this.

Comment: File file=new File(DESTINATION_PATH);
            if(file.exists()){
                 downloaded = (int) file.length();
                 connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-");
            }
   }else{
            connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
   }

Answer (score 3):

Your zip file is corrupted because you think that the stream resumes from the range byte that you specified. It actually streams from the beginning again, and so you have a file bigger than the original. Long story short, your server does not support the range property.